# Disable JIT Debugger VS2010 WS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, registry, jit, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a problem on my windows 2012 r2 server,

Sometimes an message comes up with an question if i would like to debug an running process (probably from iis but that is not mentiont)

As long as i don't not press yes or no the sites keep running but on the second i press no the site restarts. I tested this by check all response times form the sites which are running on the server.

I have the following Development Software installed:

- Visual studio 2013 ultimate with blend for visual studio
- SQL Server Management studio 2014

I tried the following things (found on similar questions):

- Disabeling JIT debugger in visual studio
- Try to remove the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger.
- try to set the registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script\Settings\JITDebug
- disabled script debugging in internet options

And i stumbled upon the following problems trying the above things:
Both the registries named did not exist on the server.
I also disabled the JIT debugger in VS 2013 but there is still an instance of the JIT debugger of VS2010, which is strange since its not installed.

Disabling JIT debugger in VS2013 did help some, at first i could choose between an 2013 or a 2010 instance. But now i would like to remove the JIT debugger of the VS2010 instance to.

What can i try more, or what did i do wrong with the things i tried so far?

**UPDATE1:**

[image: screenshot JIT chooser]

**UPDATE2:**

[image: screenshot installed software]
Could it be the visual studio 2010 shell (Islotated), if i try to open it it gives an error on a licence. If it is this program is it save to remove it?

**UPDATE3:**

Since this question is marked as duplicate i would lie to explain why it is not. The answer given in the question which is said to be the same do not apply for my problem. As said in my question i tried all those things but none of them worked. or the given registries did not exist. I really would liken answer on my problem, and if there is anything i can do to help or to make my question better please say so

Comment: @Downvoter, if you vote down, i would like to know why so i can improve this and any following questions

Comment: Didn't downvote, but your 'explanation' doesn't qualify as such.  "The answers there didn't work for me" doesn't mean the question isn't a duplicate.  It simply means someone needs to answer that question with a solution that works for you.  If you don't want your question to be a duplicate, describe how it is different than the problem described in the duplicate.